# CSS keyframes motion is not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

http://plnkr.co/edit/46U9HFEJ3bWoYnvmeulY?p=preview

In this plnkr above, I want the keyframes animation to make the links move from left to right with opacity change on load. However, I can only see the opacity change, and the horizontal movement that's supposed to run from 100px left to 0px is not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Code below:

CSS:

```
a {
  /*On Load Animation*/
  animation: loadLink 0.5s ease;
  -moz-animation: loadLink 0.5s ease;
  -o-animation: loadLink 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-animation: loadLink 0.5s ease;
}

/*On Load Animation*/
@keyframes loadLink {
  from {opacity: 0; left: -100px;}
  to {opacity: 1; left: 0px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes loadLink {
  0% {opacity: 0; left: -100px;}
  100% {opacity: 1; left: 0px;}
}

@-o-keyframes loadLink {
  0% {opacity: 0; left: -100px;}
  100% {opacity: 1; left: 0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes loadLink {
  0% {opacity: 0; left: -100px;}
  100% {opacity: 1; left: 0px;}
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li><a class="google" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
    <li><a class="yahoo" href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo</a></li>
  </ul>

</html>
```

Comment: left by itself wont do anything without position: relative/absolute/fixed/etc.

Comment: use position : relative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
a {
  position: relative;
}
```

to your CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
li {
  padding: 12px;
}
a {
  /*On Load Animation*/
  animation: loadLink 0.5s ease;
  -moz-animation: loadLink 0.5s ease;
  -o-animation: loadLink 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-animation: loadLink 0.5s ease;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Here Your New Code
 [(click here)](http://jsbin.com/kepakihava/edit?html,css,output)